# Displaying what each Hex Byte Represents in a Network Packet Hex Dump

Tags: python, networking, hex, wireshark, packet

[Wirehark Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWQxk.png)

As can be seen in the image above, in Wireshark, we can click any hexadecimal byte, and we will get which part it represents in the Packet Layer data.

I am trying to achieve the same effect but in Python. I have a Pcap file and its Hex Dump. I also have an array with the packet layer information that looks like the following:

```
Array: Packet Layer Information: 
[ { "layer_name" : "eth", "layer_len" : 14, "layer_start" : 0 }, { . . . } ... { . . . } ]
```

The array that contains the hexadecimal bytes I wish to link with the Packet Layer Data looks like this:

```
Array: Highlighted Bytes:
[ { "layer" : "ip", "position_in_layer" : 10, "byte" : "e0" }, { } ... { } ]
```

I am trying to link these hexadecimal bytes and print out what data they represent in the layer, however, from what I have seen, the Layers' structures are not always fixed, and there are a lot of layer and network protocol types.

I have tried using libraries like Pyshark and Scapy, but they do not have the functionalities that I am looking for. In Scapy, I can convert a Hex Dump to a Network Packet, however, when I print the layers, they are always only Eth followed by Raw. The layers after the Eth are a part of its payload.

I want to find a way, whether in Python, or by integrating another language, to be able to print what any byte in a packet layer represents.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer from another source, so I'll submit it in case anyone else needs it.

There is a **tshark** command that can convert a **pcap** file into a **pdml** file. The command is as follows:

```
tshark -r input.pcap -T pdml > output.pdml
```

In this **pdml** file, there is all types of information regarding the **pcap**  file, including information about the **hexdump**, and what each Packet Layer Data represents in the **hexdump**.

Therefore, the solution is to do the following:

1. Read the **pcap** file and convert it to **pdml**
2. Read the **pdml** (xml) file, and collect from it the information required, including **position** of Packet Layer Data in their **Hexdumps**.
3. Compare the positions collected with the hexadecimal position that I have, and acquire what it represents.